# frequency() and cycle() of a monthly xts object returns value "1"

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a monthly xts object, and the function `frequency()` returns a value of 1, however I would expect 12. The function `cycle()` also does not return month numbers, but instead a value of 1 for each observation.

```
library('quantmod')
getSymbols("GS10", src="FRED")
frequency(GS10)
cycle(GS10)
```

Comment: A daily object with one date in each month is not a monthly object.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - I'm not sure why you think it is a daily object. There is one observation per month, hence monthly object. As another example, one observation per year is an annual observation, not a daily observation.

Comment: `"Date"` class times are daily objects.  It doesn't matter that there happens to be one date per month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
time(GS10) <- as.yearmon(time(GS10))
```